# How to install Azure CLI Billing Account

Tags: azure, azure-cli

I am trying to run
`az billing account list`

However, when I run this I get:

```
az billing: 'account' is not in the 'az billing' command group. See 'az billing --help'. If the command is from an extension, please make sure the corresponding extension is installed. To learn more about extensions, please visit https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/azure-cli-extensions-overview
```

I have installed the `account` extension but it still has not worked.

If I run it in the Cloud Shell I get:

```
Command group 'billing account' is in preview and under development. Reference and support levels: https://aka.ms/CLI_refstatus
[]
```

so I do get a response here.

I cannot find anything to install this extension or preview extentions. 
Repo doesn't have it https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli 
Python Repo doesn't have it https://pypi.org/user/microsoft/ 
No information on the Documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/billing/2019-10-01-preview/billingaccounts 
listing the extensions doesn't show anyting https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/azure-cli-extensions-overview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The upgraded billing commands are shipped with Azure CLI 2.15.0 and the Cloud Shell you are using with Azure might be an older version, Try to update and see

Comment: Amazing that solved it. For reference for others to upgrade pre V2.11.0 you can use Chocolatey. ` choco upgrade azure-cli`